# Pandas Series has a column date, but then says it doesn't exit

Tags: pandas, series

I am dumbfounded. I have a `pandas` `series` called `ser` like this:

```
Date
2010-08-10    7.95
2010-08-11    7.67
2010-08-12    7.72
```

If I say:

```
ser['Date'].loc[0]
```

It says

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Date'
```

How do I get the the date at integer `index` `n`? So for example, `ser[0]` (whatever the syntax is) would return `2010-08-10`

Comment: That is the index of the series. Not a column. `ser.index[0]`?

Comment: Okay. How do I get the Date at location zero?

Comment: `ser.index[0]` should produce -> '2010-08-10' no?

Comment: Thanks that works. Looks like Series are indexed starting at one not zero?

Comment: It should be zero?